# date_part doesn't count as a day if time difference is less

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date

I calculate the day difference between 2 dates with date_part

```
DATE_PART('day', '2017-11-17 13:54:15' - '2017-11-12 18:05:18')
```

The day difference in here is 5 days when calculated. 
However the sql returns as 4 since for the last day it has not been 24 hours. 
But I would like to count it as 1 day.

How can I do this?

Comment: use something more precise than day (divided by 24 if hours, 3600 if minutes, etc.), take `floor` of that, and add one if it is greater than zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
DATE_PART('day'
          date_trunc('day', '2017-11-17 13:54:15'::timestamp) - date_trunc('day', '2017-11-12 18:05:18'::timestamp)
         )
```